# Can a child who arrived on an accompanied UK tourist visa stay in the UK without the parent who was issued the visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, children, thai-citizens

My wife and son (both Thai citizens) are in the UK on a tourist visa (we haven’t sorted the permanent residency things yet). My son’s visa is accompanied with my wife. Can she leave the UK while my son stays with me until she comes back? His visa isn’t due to expire for months, so won’t be overstaying, but I’m worried because it says “accompanied by” her. Will this have bad implications for the future when she tries to return? (I am a British citizen)

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question tagged "UK-Citizens" ? Please edit the question text (using the "edit" button below the tags) to state the citizenships of your wife, and your child, and yourself.

Comment: Just edited. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us why your son is not a British citizen himself?

Comment: It’s unrelated, just looking for advice on this specific scenario please guys. Thanks

Comment: Update: called UKVI directly, they say there’s no issue with her leaving him here just he can’t travel alone. They said he has his own visa even tho it’s accompanied. Great news